# Increase tap target of View without modifying position

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I’ve got this little guy:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 4) {
    Text("Name")
        .font(.subheadline).bold()
    TextField("Name", text: self.$name)
}
```

and he looks like this:
[image]

Now I want to increase the tap target so you can tap anywhere in the VStack to bring up the keyboard for the TextField. What’s a good way to do that?

I considered adding `onTapGesture` to the VStack but seems it’s not possible to trigger become first responder for TextFields, so seems I need to increase the TextField frame to have a larger tap target. Maybe put it in a ZStack instead with padding above, but a complication is how would I ensure it’s visually stacked below the header when the header height is dynamic? Perhaps `contentShape` could be used to somehow add padding to it?

Comment: SwiftUI `TextField` does not have capability for now to become focusable programmatically, so instead of workarounds I recommend to use `UIViewRepresentable` with UITextField for this purpose. There are a lot of posts on SO how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can create subclass of `UITextField` and override `point(inside:with:`) method:

```
open override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let bounds = self.bounds
    let extended = bounds.insetBy(dx: -10, dy: -10)
    let inside = extended.contains(point)
    return inside
}
```

and use your custom subclass of `UITextField` in SwiftUI. 
May be you have to create `VStack` subclass to allow touches outside of the `VStack` if touch lies in one of it subviews (with extended touch field).